# Why does :r!vi jam my terminal?

Tags: external-command, terminal

Is it legal to do `:r!vi` in vi?

A friend asked me to try it and it jammed my terminal. What exactly causes this? Is there anyway to recover the terminal without closing it and opening a new one?

Comment: It jams your terminal.

Comment: I think this question would be more on topic/high-quality if you [edit] it to be more about the practical side. For example "What causes my terminal to freeze when I do this command" and "(How) Can I recover from this aside from closing the terminal"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for *why* it jams your terminal it's because `:r!` reads a command from your terminal and inserts it into the buffer. Since it's trying to insert the output of the `vi` command, it's waiting for `vi` to finish. But all it does is open another instance of vi, which never returns.

> Is it legal?

Technically, yes. `:r!` takes a valid shell command and `vi` is a valid shell command. It's just not advised because of the aforementioned behavior.

See [`:help :r!`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#%3Ar%21) for more info.